# Twilio sending multiple Images to WhatsApp

Tags: image, twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I am currently trying to send multiple pictures to WhatsApp via Twilio and got it working with one.
Already read the other Questions and this one might be an easy one.

How do I send multiple Images in one Message?

This is what I have currently and what I tried, but the second image is never sent:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    var client = context.getTwilioClient();

    console.log("Sende Antwort")
    client.messages.create({
        to: event.From,
        from: event.To,
        body: "Sekunde, mache dir eben deinen Stoff klar."
    }, function(err, res){
        console.log("Sende Katzenbilder")
        let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
        let message = twiml.message();
        message.body("Hier ist dein wöchentlicher Cat-Content!")
        message.media("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566927467984-6332be7377d0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80");
        message.media("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1548247416-ec66f4900b2e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=663&q=80")

        callback(null, twiml)
    })
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible via the underlying API

Sending Media Messages

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/media

> The above sample shows multiple different objects such as audio, document, image, sticker, and video for illustration purposes only. A valid request body contains only one of them.

Comment: Thanks for answering Alan, on their site it says that you can send up to 10 files if not over 5 MB. Is there any way to send more than one picture in a message/more than one message with just one input from the customer/user?

Comment: Did some testing selecting / sending multiple images from the WhatsApp client on my iOS device to a Twilio number and even though you can select multiple images, the app just loops through the selection and sends each as an individual message (you get four inbound WhatsApp messages toward Twilio). So, you would need to add the same type of logic to your application from Twilio outbound, where if the user selects multiple images via your UI, you look through each image as a separate outbound API request, https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api (Send a WhatsApp message with media example).

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

WhatsApp only supports sending one image at a time with a message.

In the [Twilio API for WhatsApp documentation, this is pointed out](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/tutorial/send-and-receive-media-messages-whatsapp-nodejs#what-is-twiml) (emphasis mine):

> To send back a media in your WhatsApp reply, you need to include the media TwiML element with the URL to the media file. *One media attachment is supported per message, with a size limit of 5MB*.

You could try sending more than one message though, by using `twiml.message` more than once. Try:

```js
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    var client = context.getTwilioClient();

    console.log("Sende Antwort")
    client.messages.create({
        to: event.From,
        from: event.To,
        body: "Sekunde, mache dir eben deinen Stoff klar."
    }, function(err, res){
        console.log("Sende Katzenbilder");
        let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
        let message = twiml.message();
        message.body("Hier ist dein wöchentlicher Cat-Content!");
        message.media("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566927467984-6332be7377d0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80");
        let message2 = twiml.message();
        message2.media("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1548247416-ec66f4900b2e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=663&q=80");

        callback(null, twiml)
    })
};
```